# Ubuntu 13.10 login screen does not recognize my password

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, login

Recently i installed Ubuntu 13.10 but in log-in screen i can't enter password.

whatever i type is nothing recognized by screen and i can not log in into my account but if i log-in into guest account and after that i can log-in into my account.

So every time first i need to log-in with guest account and then i can log-in with my account. Please help me if anyone know the solution.i am using one keyboard layout.Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the `*` when you type your password? Its not clear what you mean "nothing recognized by screen".

Comment: Yes.I cant see the * ..

Comment: Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697352/ubuntu-freezes-on-boot-at-tmp-mount-prompt/23024232#23024232 for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell.
- Do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.
- If not, do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and try a login).

[This solution I took from ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) worked for me.